# AVPlayer playbackBufferFull called but currentItem.playbackBufferFull is false

Tags: objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a AVPlayer where I observe playbackBufferFull with:

```
player.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: [.New, .Initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
```

`observeValueForKeyPath` is called and I have the following code

```
if keyPath == "playbackBufferFull" {
      print("\(player.currentItem?.playbackBufferFull)")
}
```

which prints `Optional(false)`.

Why is the property still false? Shouldn't it be true? Why am i seeing this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you removing observer instead adding it? To observe value change you need to `addObserver` instead `removeObserver`. also override `observeValueForKeyPath` method. Read this wonderful [blog by NSHipster on KVO](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) for more detail.

Comment: I copied the wrong piece of code, updating the question. Thank you

Comment: Try removing .Initial